# How can I create a TCP connection and stream that can be used by all buttons in a GUI?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, tcp, stream

I am trying to create a GUI for a server in a TCP connection. I want to have a button that creates the connection and possibly an underlying stream, and then have other buttons that send serialized commands over this stream. I'm running into issues because each button acts as a sub procedure, so I believe the stream is outside of the scope and unavailable for each button.

I've tried creating the stream outside of the buttons, but the below code throws an error at `myServer.Start()`, saying that myServer isn't declared.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim myIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("my ip")
Dim myServer As New TcpListener(myIP, 800)
    myServer.Start() 'Error line

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Stream Write Stuff
End Sub

End Class
```

I've also tried listening at the start of every button press, but after connecting once the `myServer.Start()` pauses indefinitely while listening for connection attempts that aren't coming.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click      
    myServer.Start()
    Dim myClient As TcpClient = myServer.AcceptTcpClient() 
    Dim myStream As NetworkStream = myClient.GetStream
    myStream.Write(xxx)
End Sub
```

How can I create a connection and stream that is available to all the buttons I would add to the GUI?

Comment: The top `myServer.Start()` is illegal because you cant have executable code outside a method.  That should be in the start button click event, no?

Comment: If I added a Main() method at the beginning that handled the creation of the stream would there be any way to make this stream global? Or however I would go about writing code that immediately executes in a windows form

Comment: You just need to declare the stream up at the stop, then get it and start it in a click event.  I had answer ready to post to yesterday's version (which was a little clearer) of this but you deleted it before I could post.

Comment: Are you running with elevated permissions? Ports under 1024 need administrative /root permissions to work

Comment: Ok, thank you for the push in the right direction. I'll try things with the stream declared at the top and see how that interacts with other buttons. Sorry about yesterday, I began receiving downvotes and assumed the question was worded poorly.

Comment: deleting DV'd questions is a good first step to a question ban/throttle

Comment: I believe I have elevated permissions, but I'm not sure as the only thing that comes to mind is running in administrator mode and I'm not sure if that's what you meant. To be safe I'll change the ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`How can I create a connection and stream that is available to all the buttons I would add to the GUI?`

```
Public Class Form1
    ' just declare the variables
    Private myIP As IPAddress 
    Private myServer As TcpListener
    Private myStream As NetworkStream

    Sub btnStart_Click(...
       ' create the objects when you need them
        myIP = IPAddress.Parse("my ip")
        myServer = New TcpListener(...)
        myStream = myClient.GetStream
```

Declaring an object variable and creating an instance of it, are 2 different things.  You are doing both at the same time:

```
Dim myServer As New TcpListener(...)
```

The `Dim` portion declares the variable (as do `Private` | `Friend` | `Public`).  The `New` keyword creates an *instance*; you need to do both before you use an object, but they dont have to be done at the same time.  The long form makes it clearer that there are 2 parts:

```
Dim myServer As TcpListener = New TcpListener(...)
```

*Where* you declare the variables determines the Scope of the variable.  Anything inside a sub will only have procedure level scope.  It won't exist outside that procedure.  Declared up at the top, outside any procedure,`myIP`, `myServer` and `myStream` will be available everywhere in that form.

Once they are declared, you can create an instance as shown above in `btnStart_Click` (or Form Load etc).

There is also Block Scope involving constructs such as `If/End If`, `Using/End Using` and `For Each/Next`.  Variables declared inside them have a scope limited to that Block:

```
If cr IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim temp As Decimal = cr.Total
End If

lblTotal.Text = temp   ''temp' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
```

The last line will be an error because `temp` was declared (`Dim`) inside a local block, so it does not exist outside it. This would apply to `If/End If`, `Using/End Using` and `For Each/Next` --  basically, anything that results in indentation creates a local block.

See Also:

[Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)